# is mmap use already allocated block if next request fit into it?

Tags: linux, memory-management, malloc, mmap

suppose i want to allocate 3000 bytes like this

malloc(1000);
malloc(1000);
malloc(1000);

and my **malloc implementation** use **mmap()** .
So i want to know that:-

1. is malloc called 3 times mmap().
2. is mmap allocate 3 separate pages(total allocated memory is 3*4096) or it gives memory to all three requeste from one page(total allocated memory is 4096).
3. if it allocated three different pages then how i can make my alloc to do it with only one page.

Comment: Most malloc implementations will maintain an internal pool and only allocate new VM pages when needed.

Comment: paul  do u mean that it allocate memory to all three request from one page...

Answer (score 1):

The mmapping behavior of Linux's (that is, GNU libc's) `malloc` is described in the manpage `mallopt(3)`. `malloc` uses a "dynamic `mmap` threshold" that starts off at 128kB, but this may automatically be adjusted upward based on a process's allocation patterns. Smaller allocations are served using an old-school free list, and the initial threshold can be set using environment variables or the `mallopt` function.

So `malloc` will almost certainly not `mmap` three 4kB pages, but whether or not it keeps the allocations in a single page is not guaranteed. You can either do a manual `mmap` or, if two pages is ok, do a single `malloc`:

```
char *a = malloc(3000);
// check for errors
char *b = a + 1000;
char *c = b + 1000;
// don't forget that you must free a, and only a, to free b and c
```

Comment: iarsmans it really help me but i still have a doubt.I want to implement my own malloc using mmap. And malloc dont know wether the request coming from same process or different process so i want ot know what is default output in both the cases...

Comment: @Deepak: `malloc` requests always come from within the process, unless you're doing something really fancy.